# Identify the if the computer that Java Application runs is the host of the SQL Server Instance

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am developing a java application that uses SQL Server 2012 (and above) as the database. I have written a class that will be used to create a database backup from the application without going to the back end. 
In this class, I have a `JFileChooser` which is launched by a `JButton`. The user then browses and chooses a location on the server or the network where to save the backup then saves this as the default backup destination directory and progresses to backup or schedule a backup.
The path selected using the `JFileChooser` is stored in the database and whenever an automatic backup is being done, this path will be used.

What I want is that when the application is running on the server to allow both **Directories on the Local Disk and on the network**, but when the application is running from a machine that is not the server, **only network directories can be set**. This is to avoid setting a disk location that is not valid to the server. For instance setting to backup in **J:\Backups** but there is no **J** partition on the server. (We can assume that these network locations will allow the backup to be created in them).

I figured out that if I could be able to establish if the current machine is the server or not, I will be able to create methods that can do this, but I am stuck at the start: How to identify if a user is working on the server machine.
Apologies if I am not very clear. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way is to add a function to the back end that validate the directory chosen, allowing you to actually check that the server can access the chosen destination from every instance of the application (this could cover other cases, like choosing a directory on the network but not reachable from the server, for example)

Otherwise, you could get the IP of the local machine and compare it with the one of the server, filtering the chosen destination if the local machine is not the server.